# Java Applet Menu

Tags: java, swing, menu, applet, awt

I'm trying to make a Java applet with a menu (stretching across the screen with different mode options), and I want to make it have two different modes.

Is the best way to do this making two different applets that are run by a application, or should I use something different like a `JFrame` (I would rather use an `Applet`), or should I use a bunch of if statements in the paint method and such?

Comment: What do you mean by menu?  Do you mean a menu bar?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options.

Personally, I would start with a custom component (say `JPanel`), which has the ability of accepting `Action`s

I would then create a `JButton` per `Action` you add on this panel.  I would then add this panel to the main, top level container.

This allows you to produce a configurable base menu and separate the logic of each menu item from the concerns of the menu interface.

Take a look at [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

Comment: Why the panel when this sounds more like a `JMenu`?  Note that `JApplet` implements `setJMenuBar(..)`.

Comment: Cause I believe OP wants some kind "dashboard" style menu, like a game menu screen...could be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should think about another possibilities if you're developing a web application, like, for instance, jQuery, JavaFX, JSF...

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question and could insight debate, at best, this should be kept to comments in the future

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of confusion there I believe. Your Applet will be your application host, the JFrame is an object that is typically a "host" on its own (standalone application), so: "*I use something different like a JFrame(I would rather use an Applet)*" makes no sense.

You want to have an applet with a menu, and to get that you have to do what you normally do in a java standalone application:

[JMenuBar - Part 1](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/guidebook/?name=JMenuBar&page=1)

You don't need to create a JFrame either, because an applet is a top level container, so using a JPanel will do.